# Hibernate join without foreign key and map only a table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hql

I'm studying the ORM pattern and the hibernate framework.

I have two tables: table Library and Table Book

```
|Library                  |  Book
+-------------------      +--------------
|libraryId :int (PK)      |bookId:int (PK)
|name:varchar             |libraryid:int
```

The column libraryid in Book isn't foreign key

For join the tables, I use the code written below

```
session.createQuery("from Book as b, Library as l where b.libraryid=l.libraryId and l.name=:name")
            .setString("name", "test" )
            .list();
```

From that code i get a list of object[]  of Book and Library class.
How can i do for get only Book class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.createQuery("select b from Book as b`...) should gives you the vales of class Book.

Comment: Andrea, the Hibernate documentation is well written and will tell you that the approach is right.